# SQLite database isn't holding multiple values under primary key in my Discord.js bot

Tags: sql, discord.js

To start off, here's my main bot.js code (Sorry if it seems like code spaghetti. I'm not the best with javascript):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const auth = require('./auth.json');
const pack = require('./package.json');
const SQLite = require('better-sqlite3');
const sql = new SQLite('./scores.sqlite');
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`    Bot: ${client.user.tag}
    Version: ${pack.version}
    Logged in and clear for takeoff.`);
});

client.on("ready", () => {
  const battle_leaderboard = sql.prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name = 'scores';").get();
  if (!battle_leaderboard['count(*)']) {
      sql.prepare("CREATE TABLE scores (id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, user TEXT, guild TEXT, points INTEGER;").run();
      sql.prepare("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_scores_id ON scores (id);").run();
      sql.pragma("synchronous = 1");
      sql.pragma("journal_mode = wal");
    }

      client.getScore = sql.prepare("SELECT * FROM scores WHERE user = ? AND guild = ?");
      client.setScore = sql.prepare("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO scores (id, user, guild, points) VALUES (@id, @user, @guild, @points);");
            client.removeScore = sql.prepare("DELETE FROM scores WHERE user=?");
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(auth.prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(auth.prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

        switch (command) {
    case 'ping':
            client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
        break;
    case 'mimic':
        client.commands.get('mimic').execute(message, args);
        break;
    case 'add_role':
        client.commands.get('add_role').execute(message, args);
        break;
    case 'remove_role':
        client.commands.get('remove_role').execute(message, args);
        break;
    case 'bl_add_point':
        if (message.member.roles.some(r=>["Fight Officiator"])) {
            let score;
            let member = message.mentions.members.first() || client.members.get(args[0]);
      score = client.getScore.get(member.id, member.guild.id);
      if (!score) {
      score = { id: `${member.guild.id}-${member.id}`, user: member.username, guild: member.guild.id, points: 0}
      }
      score.points ++;
      client.setScore.run(score);
      message.channel.send(`Looks like ${member} got a win! Good one.`);
        } else {
            message.channel.send(`Sorry, this is only usable by GFOs.`);
        };
        break;
    case '!bl_delete':
        if (message.member.roles.some(r=>["Fight Officiator"])) {
          let member = message.mentions.users.first();
          client.removeScore.run(`${member.guild.id}-${member.id}`)
      message.channel.send(`${member} has been set to zero on the leaderboard!`);
        } else {
            message.channel.send(`Sorry, this is only usable by GFOs.`);
        };
        break;
        case 'bl':
            const top5 = sql.prepare("SELECT * FROM scores WHERE guild = ? ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 5;").all(message.guild.id);
            const battleleaderboard = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                .setColor('#FFD700')
                .setTitle('The Battle Leaderboard - Current Rankings')
                .setAuthor(`RankBot`)
                .setDescription('The top fighters are displayed here.')
                .setTimestamp()
                .setFooter(`DM a Gang Fight Officiator to set up a spar with another member and possibly get your name registered onto RankBot's leaderboard!`);

            for (const data of top5) {
                 battleleaderboard.addField(client.users.get(data.user), `${data.points} Win(s)`);
                }
            message.channel.send(battleleaderboard);
            break;
};
});

client.login(auth.token);
```

I'm creating a bot that should be pretty simple:
The bot is a RankBot (at least that's what i dubbed it as), which is supposed to track the amount of wins in battles (since this is for a discord about a fighting game) using a special role that manually increments those wins with a command, then being able to pull up a leaderboard embed showing the people with the most wins. I'm testing it in a discord separate from the one it's for with a friend, and it seemingly worked until we commanded the bot to open the leaderboard. Nothing was shown. We thought it was strange, since it worked before when only one user was in the database, and I went to the PowerShell Command Line to see if there was an error message, and this showed up.

```
C:\Users\USER\Documents\OF_RankBot\bot.js:89
                                 battleleaderboard.addField(client.users.get(data.user).tag || client.members.get(data.user).tag, `${data.points} Win(s)`);
                                                                                       ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'tag' of undefined
```

We were confused by what happened, so I removed the `tag` part of the command and used it again. The embed showed up this time, but it looked like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88tkK.png)
I assumed that what went wrong was that since they both had the same number of wins listed, the part of the bl command that sorts the users was confused. I then went and used `bl_add_point` on me and tried again. The near exact same embed was shown.

My guess as to what went wrong was that I messed up at some point when setting up the `bl_add_point` command, but I'm not sure how to fix the issue.

This isn't part of the main problem, but I can't seem to get `bl_delete` working either. No errors are shown when I use it. In fact, seemingly nothing happens. I'm not sure if these issues are connected, but I really only need the main issue fixed. 
Thanks in advance.

edit: I found out partially what happened with the `bl_delete` issue, which was I simply put the prefix into the case when the prefix was already defined. Now when I put in the command, the PowerShell responds with:

```
C:\Users\USER\Documents\OF_RankBot\bot.js:72
                  client.removeScore.run(`${member.guild.id}-${member.id}`)
                                                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

Comment: "The embed showed up this time, but it looked like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88tkK.png)." When translating a [User](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) object to a string, Discord.js uses the string that would show their mention. However, field titles do **not** support mentions. That's why the embed is shown using the literal string.

Comment: @slothiful I understand that it doesn't use mentions, but changing the `addField` output to the user's username or straight id still pulls up a working one and an undefined one, so whether the output is a mention or not is irrelevant.